# Understanding the deep copy constructor in Java

Tags: java, constructor, copy, deep-copy

I have a main class called Bar that calls the class Foo, and I think I put in a deep constructor correctly

The purpose of a deep copy constructor is to copy the contents of one object to another object and changing the copied object shouldn't change the contents of the original, correct?

My code does that, but I don't understand why when I set the original object variable, the copying object doesn't contain that set variable, it just contains the default constructor variable.

```
public class Bar
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Foo object = new Foo();
        object.setName1("qwertyuiop");



//the below line of code should copy object to object2?
        Foo object2 = new Foo(object);          
        System.out.println(object.getName1());

//shouldn't the below line of code should output qwertyuiop since object2 is a copy of object? Why is it outputting the default constructor value Hello World?
        System.out.println(object2.getName1()); 

//changes object2's name1 var to test if it changed object's var. it didn't, so my deep copy constructor is working

        object2.setName1("TROLL");
        System.out.println(object2.getName1()); 
        System.out.println(object.getName1());
    }


}

public class Foo
{

    //instance variable(s)
    private String name1;

    public Foo()
    {
        System.out.println("Default Constructor called");
        name1= "Hello World";

    }
    //deep copy constructor
    public Foo(Foo deepCopyObject)
    {   

        name1 = deepCopyObject.name1; 

    }
    public String getName1() {
    return name1;
}
public void setName1(String name1) {
    this.name1 = name1;
}
}
```

Comment: Could you show where you're calling deepCopy?

Comment: Foo object2 = new Foo(object);

Comment: Your described symptom does not happen for me with this code.

Comment: sorry, I found the bug in my code because I copied and pasted the default constructor argument in my deep constructor and forgot to change it to name1

Answer (score 7, accepted):

That's *not* deep copy.  Java is *not* C++.  You are free to write a copy constructor that takes a Foo instance and initializes it with another Foo, but there's no language support to help you with the implementation.  It's completely up to you.

You also should know that Java doesn't require a copy constructor the same way C++ does.  Java objects live on the heap.  The thing you pass to a method is a reference to an object on the heap, not a copy of an object.

You can write a copy constructor, but it's up to you how it acts.  You've got to be very careful:

```
public class Foo {
    private Map<String, Bar> barDictionary;

    public Foo() {
        this.barDictionary = new HashMap<String, Bar>();
    }

    public Foo(Foo f) { 
        // What happens here is up to you.  I'd recommend making a deep copy in this case.
        this.barDictionary = new HashMap<String, Bar>(); 
        this.barDictionary.putAll(f.barDictionary);  // Question: What about the Bar references?  What happens to those?
    }
}
```

Comment: You might create a custom Cloneable.clone() implementation, which will be clear about what it's doing.

Comment: No, Cloneable suffers from the same problems, because it can't guarantee that Bar implemented it, too.  (You might not have written it.)

Comment: I am looking at this technique. It is not clear whether implementing a copy constructor for Bar will take care of the deep copy. Does barDictionary.putAll(...) know to call the copy constructor for Bar?

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, because `String` is immutable, your `Foo` doesn't really have any depth, so the difference between a deep copy and a shallow copy doesn't really exist. For non-immutable type fields, setting `this.field = other.field` will make `this` a shallow copy. You will need to make a deep copy of `other.field` (recursively until you reach objects with only immutable or primitive fields).

Secondly, to answer the question in the comment in you code, it works correctly for me. `System.out.println(object2.getName1());` does output `qwertyuiop`.

Comment: name1 = deepCopyObject.name1;  is just a shallow copy correct? Just how do I make a deep copy of other.field?

Comment: Generally, you use a deep copy constructor if it has one, or clone() if it is clonable, or rebuild it manually.

Comment: So immutable objects will act like a deep copy of an mutable object, correct? That's why object doesn't change if I change object2? What about if I add an instance variable of type int? Will changing the int in object2 affect object's int?

Comment: No, No and no. Assigning object1.name to object2.name still points both references to the same object, but the object can't change, so you don't care. object1 doesn't change because you are not changing the underlying String (you can't), but rather changing the object object2.name points to. int is primitive, so a variable stores the actual value, not a reference. Changing an int variable can not affect any other int variable.